# Do changes made in one gnu-screen terminal populate in another terminal with ongoing process

Tags: expo, alpine-linux, gnu-screen

I am running a local development environment from the command line with one GNU-screen terminal running a text editor and the other running a continuous build process (Expo).

I want to know if changes made to a file with a text-editor in one GNU-Screen terminal immediately take effect in another terminal with the ongoing process, or if GNU-Screen waits for the process to end before updating the file system?

If not, is there a program or GNU-screen option that will allow this to occur so I don't have to restart the build each time I make a change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to files take effect as soon as the file is written to disk.

You can verify this as follows:

1. In screen one, write a file change to disk.
2. In screen two, view your change.